# Sticky top bar obscures full screen code snippets

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-snippets, top-bar

The top menu bar, when set to sticky, hides content when one run a snippet in full screen.

Is there some new setting to control this that I might have missed?, or someone else missed something :)

Tested on Chrome, Firefox and Edge, all behaves the same.

[image]

Comment: I'm fairly sure this has been pointed out before....

Comment: @JonClements Maybe, but as I just noticed it (and couldn't find any already posted), I posted....better one to many than none, right? And simple to delete

Comment: Yeah... Can't seem to find it either (hopefully I'm not just imagining it). No worries.

Comment: @JonClements Nobody seen this yet? And btw, if I'm not mistaken, it worked properly the day before I posted this.

Comment: I spotted this a few days ago when it hid an example Bootstrap navbar docked to the top of the screen. Worked around it with `body { margin-top: 4em; }`

Comment: Doesn't affect non sticky top-bar. So workaround : *Disable stickiness* in your prefs > Navigation

Comment: @Conan Do you use Tampermonkey, or similar, to override those setting?

Comment: @LGSon no, I just added the CSS to the snippet as this was a one-off (thus far).

Comment: @Conan Aha..okay, got that.

Comment: nav's `z-index` (1050) is greater than stack-snippets's `z-index` (1030).

Comment: Can confirm on Chrome 58 as well, was just about to report this.

Comment: I only noticed it just now, so apparently we're not using full-screen often enough. And it's in all main browsers even, not just some niche ones.

Comment: Here is another example. (Deleted question - only admins can see it -
 probably.) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464378/what-is-wrong-with-my-bootstrap-4-alpha-6-tabbed-panes-tabs-not-switching

Comment: @JonClements Now somebody did something here. The full screen snippet is now _on top_ of the top bar, which is great, but what is not so great is that the _Close_ button/link is now missing. If one is in edit mode preparing an answer and goes to _full screen_ to test how it looks, one will lose everything, as their is no way to get back to the edit window. Should I post another question or what?

Comment: @LGSon https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350699/close-snippet-obstructed-in-full-screen

Comment: @PraveenKumar Found your post 3-4 days ago, so great ... though I posted the issue first, here :)

Comment: @LGSon No... Yours is not what I am talking about... Ha ha... There's a difference bro. Mine's just the close button thing.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Sorry, didn't mean my post, meant my comment above about the Close button :) ...  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349740/sticky-top-bar-obscures-full-screen-code-snippets?noredirect=1#comment481717_349740

Comment: @LGSon We are confused. LoL. And I am hungry.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Go and eat... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sad that this still happens (at least, for sticky top bars), but in the mean time, here's a stylesheet override that fixes the issue while also not messing with the site in other ways:

```css
iframe.snippet-box-edit[style*="fixed"] {
    top: 60px !important;
    height: calc(100% - 60px) !important;
}
```

You can install it with Stylish ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/), [home page](https://userstyles.org/)) or something. AFAIK `calc` is [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc). `60px` seems to be the hard coded top bar height from *all.css*, so it should always line up. Replace it with whatever if you're using a custom top bar stylesheet with a narrower bar.

Just in case it's not clear, this is a style that needs to be applied to the *site*, not used in your snippet. It will fix it for all snippets.

Comment: I'm sad more that this still happens in 2021! I hope that there are people working on SO sites....or not?