# Close Snippet obstructed in Full Screen

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, user-interface, user-experience

[Alter the z-index of fixed top bar when using Full Screen Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350638/alter-the-z-index-of-fixed-top-bar-when-using-full-screen-snippets) has been fixed. But click on the full screen preview and try to close the snippet?

```html
Hello! Click on the full page above right and try to come back to the question here / minimize this?
```

**Solution:**

Need to add this simple fix:

```css
.snippet-code .popin {
  z-index: 9001;
}
```

Comment: One way to close if you accidentally ducked up. Click on the page, Shift Tab, Enter. 

Comment: You can also write in the address bar `javascript:$('.snippet-code .popin').click()` - Problem solved! ;)

Comment: LoL. @AlonEitan I don't wanna mess up with `javascript:` in the address bar.

Comment: Did code changes on SO stop going through QA?

Comment: @j08691 I know they *dont* have a written document on z-index standards as of several weeks ago, but that it was on their radar to create. I'm guessing they still haven't created one yet.

Comment: @TylerH Ha ha... :)

Comment: The original question was not marked as status-fixed. Are you sure it was *really* fixed?

Comment: @EMBarbosa Not exactly... Something happened at least... My question was fixed.

Comment: @EMBarbosa I don't see [meta-tag:status-fixed] in [Sticky top bar obscures full screen code snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349740/1518921) (revisions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/349740/revisions)

Comment: I would upvote this 100 times if I could. Really annoying bug at the moment. Please fix this.

Comment: My [original question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349740/sticky-top-bar-obscures-full-screen-code-snippets) hasn't got [status-fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-fixed) yet, though they fixed the _z-index_ on the sticky top bar, but not its _Close_ button/link

Comment: @LGSon Right...

Comment: @PraveenKumar tried that, disables scroll bar. Ugh

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I know...

Comment: @LGSon Oh yeah youa re here.

Comment: Yes....all over the place :)

Comment: Its working again, Close button is back ... yeaaaaah :) .. or at least for me

Comment: @LGSon Looks like they fixed! Yay!!!

Comment: Still don't fixed (Firefox Windows).